# Copy Allocated Struct in C

Tags: c, memory-management, struct

Okay, so I have a struct of structs of structs of stru...
Is there anyway to copy the entire struct with all the data into a new one without having to allocate a whole other series of structs?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just assign:

```
MyStruct a;
MyStruct b;

...

a = b;
```

This performs a *shallow copy*; if any of the structures contain pointers, then it's only the pointer is copied, not the stuff being pointed to.  If you need a *deep copy*, you will have to write your own routine.

Comment: +1.  However, depending on your environment a simple assignment may not be sufficient.  Some compilers will emit a literal call to `memcpy`, so if that symbol isn't defined in your environment (or has strange semantics), you might find yourself in trouble.

Comment: @CarlNorum: That would be extremely annoying, given that the above is well-defined C89...

Comment: It is in fact extremely annoying, but unfortunately real.

Comment: @CarlNorum: Undoubtedly.  Can you suggest a compiler that does this?

Comment: GCC, clang, and Visual Studio all do it.  In fact, said behaviour cannot even be avoided in some versions.

Comment: Here's a [Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410595/getting-gcc-to-compile-without-inserting-call-to-memcpy) that talks about it, and a [link to the GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html) describing the required functions - specifically `memcpy`, `memmove`, `memset` and `memcmp`.